# add command to path in OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, console, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to add a variable to my path in my OSX Mavericks using `~/.bash_profile`, but when I type it, I get this error:

```
-bash: /Users/MyUser/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

I've read somewhere that in Mavericks it's done in a different way.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using ._bash_profile and .bashrc on Maverick, this work well.
If it does not exist, you can create and edit it using, vim, emacs or any editor.

$ touch ~/.bash_profile

$ open ~/.bash_profile -a "TextEdit"

This is my .bash_profile, the second line (export PATH) is what you are looking for.

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

See, it works ! Ahahah [goo.gl/eDBVD0](http://goo.gl/eDBVD0)